# Prevent displaying PHP File through URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i would like to make it impossible to open a PHP file directly through an Url but keep it still accessible through jQuery. Right now it is possible to enter this URL in the Browser:

```
    http://domain.com/php/member.php
```

But i would like to prevent that. If someone types this in the Browser Url than i would like to redirect everyone to http://domain.com with htaccess. But it must be still possible to send variables through the own Website with jQuery to the PHP File.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it access directly put it outside the web root and use a php script to interact with it. jQuery/JavaScript is client side. If it can access the file, then the client will be able to also. You would be better off using PHP to send/receive info to jQuery and hide that file outside the web root so there is no direct access.

Comment: Thats a great idea! But i need to solve this problem the way i mentioned becouse the whole project can not be changed right now this way. Thanks!

Comment: You can't block direct access to it using .htaccess and still use client side scripting to interact with it. You could probably block access to it, then use jQuery to call anther PHP file that can include the member.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [htaccess redirect](http://www.htaccessredirect301.com) to generate the code to redirect domain.com/php/member.php to domain.com. You can use a 301 redirect like the one above.

Comment: Hi :) Is it also possible to block every single PHP File which is inside the (php) domain.com/php/ directory somehow? And will the variables still be arriving at the PHP File contained in the http://domain.com/php/member.php directory after that change? The PHP File needs to stay there http://domain.com/php/member.php and it should still be possible to send the variables to the PHP File located here http://domain.com/php/member.php. I just dont want that someone can enter the path to the member.php in the Browser directly. Thanks!